# ld cannot find libraries even though they exist

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, raspberry-pi

EDIT: Apparantly ~ doesn't work here and only in the shell, replace ~ with '$HOME' and it should work, thanks for everybody who answered.

Trying to compile a project here but it seems it can't find the libraries even though they exist, here is the output of my line and proof that the libraries exist.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/Car $ g++ Car.cpp -I~/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -L~/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv -lraspicamcv -L~/git/userland/build/lib -lmmal_core -lmmal -lmmal_util -lvcos -lbcm_host -I/usr/include/opencv -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lopencv_video -lopencv_imgproc -lpthread -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lraspicamcv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmmal_util
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvcos
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lbcm_host
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
pi@raspberrypi ~/Car $ find ~/ -name libraspicamcv.so
/home/pi/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv/libraspicamcv.so
pi@raspberrypi ~/Car $ find ~/ -name libmmal_core.so
/home/pi/git/userland/build/lib/libmmal_core.so
pi@raspberrypi ~/Car $ find ~/ -name libmmal.so
/home/pi/git/userland/build/lib/libmmal.so
pi@raspberrypi ~/Car $
```

EDIT: Tried doing

```
ld -L~/git/userland/build/lib -lmmal_core --verbose
```

and it gave me

```
attempt to open ~/git/userland/build/lib/libmmal_core.so failed
```

but ~/git/userland/build/lib/libmmal_core.so does infact exist, so for some reason it can't seem to open the file while it exists.

Comment: just a guess, but I think the ~ might cause the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding "~" to your home directory is a feature of the shell, and it is not expanded "inside" a parameter such as `-I~/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv`.

When the linker goes looking for the library, it doesn't ask your shell where it is — it tries to find the literal path "~/git/robidouille/raspicam_cv", which doesn't exist.

Replace "~" with "$HOME", which *will* be expanded by the shell.

Comment: Oh, that worked, Thanks! Didn't know ~ was only part of the shell and didn't work inside parameters.